# How to share validation and schemas between a DRF FilterBackend and a Serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am implementing some APIs using Django Rest Framework, and using the `generateschema` command to generate the OpenApi 3.0 specs afterwards.

While working on getting the schema to generate correctly, I realized that my code  seemed to be duplicating a fair bit of logic between the `FilterBackend` and `Serializer` I was using.  Both of them were accessing and validating the query parameters from the request.

I like the way of specifying the fields in the `Serializer` (`NotesViewSetGetRequestSerializer` in my case), and I would like to use that in my FilterBackend (`NoteFilterBackend` in my case).  It would be nice to have access to the `validated_data` within the filter, and also be able to use the serializer to implement the [filtering schemas](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#pagination-schemas).

Are there good solutions out there for only needing to specify your request query params once, and re-using with the filter and serializer?

I've reproduced a simplified version of my code below.  I'm happy to provide more info on `ResourceURNRelatedField` if it's needed (it extends `RelatedField` and uses URNs instead of primary keys), but I think this would apply to any kind of field.

```
class NotesViewSet(generics.ListCreateAPIView, mixins.UpdateModelMixin):
    allowed_methods = ("GET")
    queryset = Note.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [NoteFilterBackend]
    serializer_class = NotesViewSetResponseSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        query_params_dict = request.query_params
        request_serializer = NotesViewSetGetRequestSerializer(data=query_params_dict)

        request_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        validated_data = request_serializer.validated_data
        member = validated_data.get("member_urn")
        team = validated_data.get("team_urn")

        if not provider_can_view_member(request.user, member, team):
            return custom404(
                request,
                HttpResponseNotFound(
                    "Member does not exist!. URN={}".format(member.urn())
                ),
            )

        return super(NotesViewSet, self).list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

```
class NotesViewSetGetRequestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    member_urn = ResourceURNRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(), required=True)
    team_urn = ResourceURNRelatedField(queryset=Team.objects.all(), required=True)
    privacy_scope = serializers.CharField(required=False)

    def validate_privacy_scope(self, value):
        choices = dict(Note.PRIVACY_SCOPE_CHOICES)
        if value and value not in choices:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                "bad privacy scope {}. Supported values are: {}".format(value, choices)
            )
        else:
            return value
```

```
class NoteFilterBackend(BaseFilterBackend):
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        member_urn = request.query_params.get("member_urn")
        customer_uuid = URN.from_urn(member_urn).id

        privacy_scope = request.query_params.get("privacy_scope")

        team_urn = request.query_params.get("team_urn")
        team_uuid = URN.from_urn(team_urn).id

        queryset = queryset.filter(customer__uuid=customer_uuid)
        if privacy_scope == Note.PRIVACY_SCOPE_TEAM_PROVIDERS:
            queryset = queryset.filter(team__uuid=team_uuid)

        return queryset
```